# Play authentication error

Tags: playframework

**getting this error--at line 73**

```
In {module:secure}/app/controllers/Secure.java (around line 73)

69:
         // Check tokens
70:
         Boolean allowed = false;
71:
         try {
72:
             // This is the deprecated method name
73:
             **allowed = (Boolean)Security.invoke("authenticate", username, password);**
74:
            // allowed = true;
75:
         } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e ) {
76:
             // This is the official method name
77:
             allowed = (Boolean)Security.invoke("authenticate", username, password);
78:
         }
79:
         if(validation.hasErrors() || !allowed) {
```

I tried to debugg the application but could not find proper reason for the `error.[![enter image description here][1]][1]` Please tell me how this authentication happens in play framework so that i can debugg. I do not understand the code flow.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Do you really have '**' in the beginning of line 73 and is your error really called 'error.[![enter image description here][1]][1]'?

Comment: no i dont have such kind of things,,,, i just wanted to bold it to highlight it as error.... ignore that

Comment: at starting, there was "authentify" as parameter at line number 73, i changed it to "authenticate" to see if it really works. But it didn

Comment: Also, same code is working from citrix machine (Virtual) but not from my local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java version mismatch was the issue. The application required 1.6 and mine was java 1.8